# CASE statement where conditional includes an IN statement redshift

Tags: sql, string, case, amazon-redshift

```
CASE 
   WHEN code IN ('FJS354', 'JDF334') 
      THEN 'Lower_form'
      ELSE 0 
END AS format
```

This returns an error in Redshift

> invalid input syntax for integer: "Lower_form"

I know if I change 'Lower_form' to an integer it will work however I want this column to be a string. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A case expression's different return values must have matching data types. char and int are not.

Comment: Maybe your query outputs some kind of report, but if I were you, I would just do `CASE WHEN code in ('FJS354','JDF334') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Lower_form` . It uses less space, and is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

> I want this column to be a string.

All branches of a `case` expression must return the same datatype. You are giving two literal values whose datatype is not the same (string vs integer): the database makes the decision to turn them both to integers - which is not what you want.

Rremove the ambiguity by being explicit about the datatype you want to return. That is, make this literal `0` a string:

```
CASE WHEN code in ('FJS354','JDF334') 
    THEN 'Lower_form'
    ELSE '0' 
END as format
```